# Saving JSON object in sequelize

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I am trying to save a json object that is sent by a client, in the database
The application can handle requests just fine, but i am stuck when it comes to saving the request data in the database, i am using sequelize.
Here are my models:

Schedule Model

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Schedules = sequelize.define('Schedules', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    delay: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    criteria: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {})
  Schedules.associate = (models) => {
    Schedules.hasMany(models.Commands)
  }
  return Schedules
}
```

and the commands model

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Commands = sequelize.define('Commands', {
        command: DataTypes.STRING,
        index: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },{})
    Commands.associate = (models) => {
        Commands.belongsTo(models.Schedules)
    }
    return Commands
}
```

Finally here is the request json object that is recieved

```
{
    "name": "Do Something",
    "commands": [
        "step one",
        "step two",
        "step three"
    ]
}
```

Also i need to make sure when a schedule is queried, it shall return the commands[] array in that order.
My Question is, How can i do so in sequelize, Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fist you need to import those sequelize models in file where you want to work with them:

```
const schedulesModel = require(path to your defined model Schedules)
const commands = require(path to your defined model Commands )
```

let's say you have a endpoint for POST operation:

```
exports.createSchedulesAndCommands = **async** (req, res, next) => {
```

you need to create a "parent" object first:

```
const schedule = await schedulesModel.create({name: parse.body.name});
```

then to iterate to every element of array and based on scheduled object (just created) sequelize present "magic" methods, that have sintax createAssociatedModelName.

```
await Promise.all(
      parse.body.commands.map(async command => {
        await schedule.createCommands({command: command});
      })
    );
```

You may want to consider checking documentation of sequelize realated for associations:
https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html
Hope this helps.